# How to remove duplicate points from a plot

Tags: plotting, data

I have this equation and I want to draw the contour plot.

```
-1.94178*10^24 H Te^0.5 - (
 3.2*10^-9 (7.33376*10^27 Te^(7/2) + 4.66533*10^24 Ti^(7/2)))/H + 
 7.68161*10^40 H ((5.41*10^-15 E^(-148/Ti))/Ti^(3/2) + (
 2.00122*10^-10 E^(-((
  53.124 (1 - (-0.059357 Ti + 0.0010404 Ti^2 - 
       9.1653*10^-6 Ti^3)/(
      1 + 0.20165 Ti + 0.0027621 Ti^2 + 9.8305*10^-7 Ti^3))^(1/3))/
   Ti^(1/3))))/(
    Ti^(2/3) (1 - (-0.059357 Ti + 0.0010404 Ti^2 - 
    9.1653*10^-6 Ti^3)/(
   1 + 0.20165 Ti + 0.0027621 Ti^2 + 9.8305*10^-7 Ti^3))^(5/6)))
```

I have used this code to draw the contourplot.

```
H0 = 0.042;
xyz = {}


 Do[s0 = t0 /. {Ti -> ti, Te -> te};
 h = H /. FindRoot[s0 == 0, {H, H0}];
 xyz = Append[xyz, {ti, te, h}];, {ti, 1, 200}, {te, 1, 40}]

c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
f0 = ListContourPlot[xyz, ColorFunction -> "IslandColors", 
  Contours -> c , 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[ "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
 FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)", FontSize -> 14, 
 FontFamily -> "Times"]},  
 ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#2, #2}, Background -> White] &),
 LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold], (FontSize -> 16), 
  FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
    ]
```

the problem is when i draw the plot there are some duplicate lines i don't want them to be in plot. how can i remove them.
here is the picture of the plot.[image: contourplot]

Answer (score 3):

Why not just using `ContourPlot`?

```
eq = -1.94178*10^24*H*Te^0.5 - (3.2*(7.33376*10^27*Te^(7/2) + 4.66533*10^24*Ti^(7/2)))/
(10^9*H) + 7.68161*10^40*H*(5.41/((10^15*E^(148/Ti))*Ti^(3/2)) + 
 2.00122/((10^10*E^((53.124*(1 - (-0.059357*Ti + 0.0010404*Ti^2 - (9.1653*Ti^3)/10^6)/
          (1 + 0.20165*Ti + 0.0027621*Ti^2 + (9.8305*Ti^3)/10^7))^(1/3))/Ti^(1/3)))*
   (Ti^(2/3)*(1 - (-0.059357*Ti + 0.0010404*Ti^2 - (9.1653*Ti^3)/10^6)/
       (1 + 0.20165*Ti + 0.0027621*Ti^2 + (9.8305*Ti^3)/10^7))^(5/6))));

sol = H /. Solve[eq == 0, H] // Simplify;
```

Now we can plot:

```
    ContourPlot[sol[[2]], {Ti, 1, 2000}, {Te, 1, 200}, 
 Contours -> Range[15], ColorFunction -> "IslandColors", 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
    FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)", FontSize -> 14, 
    FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold], (FontSize -> 16), 
   FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

[image]

I plotted `sol[[2]]` because `sol[[1]]` corresponds to negative contour levels.

**EDIT**

It is possible also plot this `eq` in 3D:

```
ContourPlot3D[eq == 0, {Ti, 1, 2000}, {Te, 1, 200}, {H, 1, 15}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {Range[15]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
    FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)", FontSize -> 14, 
    FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   Style["H", FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
 BaseStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["IslandColors"][#3] &)]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Without solving original equation `eq` for `H`, we can plot contours of `eq == 0` for specific values of `H`:

```
ClearAll[eq];
    eq[H_] := -1.94178*10^24*H*Te^0.5 - (3.2*(7.33376*10^27*Te^(7/2) + 4.66533*10^24*Ti^(7/2)))/
(10^9*H) + 7.68161*10^40*H*(5.41/((10^15*E^(148/Ti))*Ti^(3/2)) + 
 2.00122/((10^10*E^((53.124*(1 - (-0.059357*Ti + 0.0010404*Ti^2 - (9.1653*Ti^3)/10^6)/
          (1 + 0.20165*Ti + 0.0027621*Ti^2 + (9.8305*Ti^3)/10^7))^(1/3))/Ti^(1/3)))*
   (Ti^(2/3)*(1 - (-0.059357*Ti + 0.0010404*Ti^2 - (9.1653*Ti^3)/10^6)/
       (1 + 0.20165*Ti + 0.0027621*Ti^2 + (9.8305*Ti^3)/10^7))^(5/6))));

ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq[Range[15]], {Ti, 1, 2000}, {Te, 1, 200}, 
 ContourStyle -> ColorData["IslandColors"] /@ Rescale[Range[15]], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{"IslandColors", {1, 15}}, Range[15], LegendLabel -> "H", 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 14]], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)"}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

For b&w plot one can use `ContourStyle` option and adjust thickness and dashing (here I borrowed dashing patterns from `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` and added two types of thickness):

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq[Range[15]], {Ti, 1, 2000}, {Te, 1, 200}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive @@@ 
   Tuples[{{Black}, {Thickness[Medium], 
      Thickness[Large]}, {AbsoluteDashing[{}], 
      AbsoluteDashing[{6, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{2, 2}], 
      AbsoluteDashing[{6, 2, 2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{12, 2}], 
      AbsoluteDashing[{12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}], 
      AbsoluteDashing[{24, 2, 8, 2}], 
      AbsoluteDashing[{24, 2, 2, 2}]}}], 
 PlotLegends -> (Row[{HoldForm@H, "\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]", #}] & /@
     Range[15]), 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)"}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 14]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank ypu very much for your help. it really saved me.

Comment: I added possible use of `ContourPlot3D`, please see edited part.

Comment: thank you very much kind regards. i had some other questions: why did you put plot points?

Comment: `PlotPoints` is usually used to make plot more smooth, it may depend on particular plot whether it should be used. Mathematica uses adaptive algorithm to find sufficient number of sample points, but we can sometimes help it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comments. best regards

Comment: dear @Alx I have a question. when I try to draw contourlabels it seems there is singularity on the left side of the plot. how can I remove it?

Comment: Please, see my EDIT 2. It is something strange with my original approach with solving `eq` for `H`: those black border points in `ContourPlot` (they correspond to contour = 1) make a mess with contourlabels. In EDIT 2 I suggest to plot idividual contours for specific values of `H`, color them with desired color scheme and add `BarLegend` describing colors. Unfortunately (at least for my knowledge) it is not possible to shade between contours and add labels in this approach: we plot not one function but actually series of functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and consideration. I really appreciate it.   As I wanted the black and white version of the plot I wanted the label with on the contours too. thank you very much again.

Comment: For b&w plot you can use either `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` (with lesser number of contours because it has limited number of dashing patterns) or set `ContourStyle` option with appropriate combinations of tickness/dashing, I added b&w plot.

Comment: thank you very much. kind regards